# how to retrieve a Django model from a html template form

Tags: python, django, django-models, post, django-templates

I am having a user select from a list of Pending shift swap requests. in the html page the form is as such

```
#pending_swaps.html

{% for pending in swappie_pending_list %}
    <form action="{% url 'ShiftSwap:pending_swaps' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ pending.swapper.name }} wants to switch your {{ pending.get_swappie_day_display }} for their {{ pending.get_swapper_day_display }}
                <input type="hidden" name="Swap_Obj" value="{{ pending }}">
                <input type="submit" name="Confirm" value="Confirm">
                <input type="submit" name="Deny" value="Deny">
            </p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

in this code the swappie_pending_list is a list of Pending_Swap Model objects. However when I try to make a hidden input of value={{ pending }} it simply returns the **str** of the model instead of an instance to the model itself

here is the Pending_swap model

```
class Pending_Swap(models.Model):
    '''
    a model to house two users, and two days to keep track of which swaps are currently pending \n
    swapper: user
    swappie: who they want to swap with
    swapper_day: day they are giving up
    swappie_day: day the user wants to take
    '''
    Days_of_week = (
        ('SU', 'Sunday'),
        ('MO', 'Monday'),
        ('TU', 'Tuesday'),
        ('WE', 'Wednesday'),
        ('TH', 'Thursday'),
        ('FR', 'Friday'),
        ('SA', 'Saturday'),
    )

    swapper = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=" ", related_name='Swapper')
    swappie = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=" ", related_name='Swappie')

    swapper_day = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Days_of_week)
    swappie_day = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Days_of_week)

    confirm = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} and {1} pending swap {2} for {3}".format(self.swapper.name, self.swappie.name, self.swapper_day, self.swappie_day)
```

[image of the stack to show the different variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdiJu.png)

is there anyway to get the instance from the template instead of a string?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't fix the problem, however, as a workaround, I was able to split the str into a working form to "re get" the object

```
swap_name = swap_obj.split()
            swapper = Person.objects.get(name=swap_name[0])
            swappie = Person.objects.get(name=swap_name[2])
            swapper_day = swap_name[5]
            swappie_day = swap_name[7]
```

swap_obj is the Swap_Obj (str from the model) from the template
so the initial question was not answered but I was able to get around it.